# How to interact with deleted file

Tags: svn, revision-history

I want to interact with a file that was deleted from the svn repository recently, but when I try to do so I get a "not under version control" warning.

What I want to do specifically is to `svn cat` the original version of it out to a file for inspecting/using, but I cannot `svn log` it either, as that also gives the same warning.

If I `svn log -v` the parent directory of the old file, I can see the revision where the file was added and the one where it was deleted. The revision in which the file was added (the one I'm interested in) is r1678.

If I do `svn log -r 1678 -v path/file@1678` I get the "not under version control" warning.

If I do `svn cat -r 1678 path/file@1678` I get the "not under version control" warning.

How do I get the file?

In case it matters, the "delete" was a move to a different directory, but I'm not sure how it was moved. If I do an `svn log newpath/file` the history does not include the original location of the file, so I assumed it was moved in a manner which did not preserve the history (ie: not the same svn node). But I'm not sure. If I do an `svn log` on the parent a couple levels removed so that it includes both the old and new directories, I get the following:

```
r1804 | ...
M newpath/file

r1755 | ...
M newpath/file

r1700 | ...
D oldpath/file
A newpath/file

r1678 | ...
A oldpath/file
```

The root need here is a diff with the original version of the file as it was when it was first added, which I cannot get easily since the history is broken at the file move. If there is an easy way to do that, that would be appreciated, but that is not technically what this specific question is asking.

So how do I interact with the deleted file?

Answer (score 0):

The *deleted* file is no longer in the working copy, so you need to access the revision from the repository.

It looks like you have identified the revisions and pathnames you are interested in. Use:

```
svn info
```

from within your working copy, to find its *Relative URL*. It will look something like `^/trunk/newpath` (depending on which directory you invoke it on).

The *deleted* file can be accessed using (something like):

```
svn cat -r 1700 ^/trunk/newpath/file
```